# How do I get the unique paths in a graph in memgraph/cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, memgraphdb

Suppose I had two nodes: A and B. Now suppose I had two relations that are similar:

```
A -r1-> B
A -r2-> B
```

How do I make a query that returns just a path from A -> B? The following query returns two paths that are identical. Can we merge the results?

```
MATCH path = (start:Fen)-[r*]->(end:Fen)
WHERE start.Name = 'A'
RETURN DISTINCT(path)
```

What I am trying to solve is to find the most popular paths between nodes. so given the graph:

```
A -r1-> B
A -r2-> B
A -r3-> C
```

the query should return

```
A -r-> B
A -r-> C
```

since A -> B is the most popular it appears first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return pairs of endpoints in the results, in descending order of the number of paths between them, like so:

```
MATCH path = (start:Fen)-[*]->(end:Fen)
WHERE start.Name = 'A'
RETURN start, end, count(*) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC
```

As an aside, you depict your desired result in the form of `A -r-> B`. Assuming by `-r->` you mean all the intermediate nodes and relationships in the path, then these would all be distinct and appear in separate rows.

Comment: took me awhile to understand the counts in this query but it was essentially counting all the possible paths from start to end.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a this type of dataset:

```
CREATE (:Node {name: 'A'});
CREATE (:Node {name: 'B'});
CREATE (:Node {name: 'C'});
CREATE (:Node {name: 'D'});
CREATE (:Node {name: 'E'});
MATCH (a:Node {name: 'A'}), (b:Node {name: 'B'})
CREATE (a)-[:r1]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:r2]->(b);
MATCH (a:Node {name: 'A'}), (c:Node {name: 'C'})
CREATE (a)-[:r3]->(c);
MATCH (d:Node {name: 'D'}), (e:Node {name: 'E'})
CREATE (d)-[:r4]->(e);
MATCH (b:Node {name: 'B'}), (d:Node {name: 'D'})
CREATE (b)-[:r5]->(d);
MATCH (c:Node {name: 'C'}), (e:Node {name: 'E'})
CREATE (c)-[:r6]->(e);
```

This should work in Memgraph:

```
MATCH (start:Node {name: 'A'})-[r]->(end:Node)
WITH start, end, collect(r) AS rels
ORDER BY size(rels) DESC
RETURN start.name AS StartNode, end.name AS EndNode, size(rels) AS RelationshipCount
```

As result I get `A->B count:2`, `A->C count:1`

Comment: Doing a `collect` to then `count` its elements with `size` is a roundabout way of just getting the `count`.